# XSD regex pattern for IP number with machine name prefix?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to use a pattern with XSD for a specific attribute as seen in the following XML

```
<employee eName="bob dole"
          computerName=floor1.123.45.67.89 />
```

The computer name is either `floor1.IP` or `floor2.IP`.

My XSD file has the following

```
<xs:element name="employee">
     <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="eName" use="required" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:attribute name="computerName" use="required">
               <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction>
                         <xs:pattern value="((floor1\.)||floor2\.))|(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" />
                    </xs:restriction>
               </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have the `or` statement correct, since when I run it without the IP component it does work.  However, when I append the IP requirement it fails with my test XML.

Answer (score 1):

Numerous problems to fix here:

1. Attributes must have (single or double) quote delimiters in XML.
2. `xs:restriction` must have a `base` attribute in XSD: `base="xs:string"` would work here.
3. Your regex is not even syntactically correct.  See below for one that's both syntactically and semantically correct for your XML.

### XML

```
<employee eName="bob dole"
          computerName="floor1.123.45.67.89"/>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="employee">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="eName" use="required" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="computerName" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(floor[1|2]\.)(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```